# Elasticsearch- Adding a runtime mapped object to response

Tags: elasticsearch

I wrote this elastic query to find my products based on nested price data.
in runtime_mappings section I tried to find correct price node and in query section I'm using it for filtering.
But after this filtering I couldnt get this mapped object at the response

My query :

```
GET /products/_search
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "priceNode": {
      "type": "composite", 
      "fields": {
        "priceOfPiece": {
          "type": "double"
        }
      },
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": """
          def price =  params['_source']['prices'][0];
          emit(price)
        """
      }
    }
  }, 
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "categoryIds": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "priceNode.priceOfPiece": 10
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": ["prices", "name", "priceNode"]
}
```

My example data model :

```
{
"Id" : 1,
    "Name": "Product 1",
    "IsShipEnabled": true,
    "AllowPickupStore": true,
    "CategoryIds": [
      1
    ],
    "Prices": [
      {
        "PhysicalStoreId": 1,
        "PriceOfPiece": 10,
        "PriceOfPackage": 20,
        "PriceOfParcel": 30,
        "CustomerCategoryIdentifier": null,
        "SalesChannel": 2,
        "ErpProductType": 2
      },
      {
        "PhysicalStoreId": 1,
        "PriceOfPiece": 11,
        "PriceOfPackage": 21,
        "PriceOfParcel": 31,
        "CustomerCategoryIdentifier": "CGTS-S001.010.020",
        "SalesChannel": 2,
        "ErpProductType": 4
      },
      {
        "PhysicalStoreId": 0,
        "PriceOfPiece": 12,
        "PriceOfPackage": 22,
        "PriceOfParcel": 32,
        "CustomerCategoryIdentifier": null,
        "SalesChannel": 1,
        "ErpProductType": 1
      }
    ]
  }
```

note :  def price =  params['_source']['prices'][0]; is an example. After I solve this projection problem I will add more logic to here based on sales channel and etc

I tried to get this data with scripting field but I'm getting error like this
Code :

```
"script_fields": {
    "asd": {
      "script": {
        "source": """
        def a = doc['priceNode'];
        return a;
        """
      }
    }
  }
```

Error :
No field found for [priceNode] in mapping

Comment: First thing first, in your script you reference the field using `prices` (lowercase) and in your sample data it's `Prices` (initial uppercase). Then can you show what the mapping of the `Prices` field?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didnt mention that, after pushing my data to elasticsearch, all properties converted lowercase (first letter)
So there is no problem about lower-upper cases.

Comment: What about my last question?

Comment: `"prices": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "erpProductType": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "physicalStoreId": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "priceOfPackage": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "priceOfParcel": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "priceOfPiece": {
            "type": "double"
          },
          "salesChannel": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }`

Comment: Ok if `prices` is nested, that's the reason why you can't access prices from the top-level document in a script, because nested documents are living in their own hidden and standalone document (on the same shard as the root-level document)